# SVG how to get absolute coordinate for transform with translate and rotate in Java

Tags: java, svg, transform, svg-filters

Currently I am using batik library for SVG manipulation.
Below is my element :

```
<g id="FrontRight_1">
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M335.775,3550.251l886.631,198.611
    c0,0-17.461-467.823-190.26-756.729c-172.794-288.907-243.793-385.207-281.208-529.649
    c-37.417-144.446-65.087-385.58-29.396-544.164l-431.396-161.81c0,0-100.354,225.707-99.356,607.059
    c0.598,228.37,83.309,362.999,112.561,620.65C323.833,3164.645,338.045,3532.962,335.775,3550.251z"/>
```

Its Original Coordinate is : 190.7826,1756.51

After transform function as follow:

```
<g id="FrontRight_1" transform="translate(-1751.828610 1227.40240) rotate(270.0)"> <path d="M335.775 3550.251 L1222.406 3748.862 L1222.406 3748.862 L1204.945 3281.039 L1032.146 2992.1329 L859.352 2703.226 L788.3529 2606.926 L750.938 2462.4841 L713.521 2318.038 L685.851 2076.904 L721.542 1918.3201 L290.146 1756.51 L290.146 1756.51 L189.7919 1982.217 L190.79 2363.569 L191.388 2591.939 L274.099 2726.568 L303.3509 2984.2192 L323.833 3164.645 L338.045 3532.962 L335.775 3550.251 Z" fill="#8498d1" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="1" /> </g>
```

Need to know new absolute coordinate of above element

Thank you

Comment: are you using svg.js or not?

Comment: No ,  I am creating Java application for SVG manipulate by using batik libraries

Comment: So to summarise (because your question is a little unclear), you want to know what the new coordinates of (190.7826,1756.51) would be, if you apply the same transform, that your second `<g>` has.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Paul , yes that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batik supports the SVG DOM, so the method should be the same as it would be for the Javascript example below.

```js
var g   = document.getElementById("FrontRight_1");
var svg = g.ownerSVGElement;

var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
pt.x = 190.7826;
pt.y = 1756.51;

var groupTransformMatrix = g.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;

pt = pt.matrixTransform(groupTransformMatrix);
console.log("pt=",pt);
```

```html
<svg>
  <g id="FrontRight_1" transform="translate(-1751.828610 1227.40240) rotate(270.0)">
  </g>
</svg>
```

It should just be a matter of porting the code to Java.  I'm not a Batik user, but it should be something like the following:

```
SVGDocument   document = canvas.getSVGDocument();
SVGGElement   g        = (SVGGElement) document.getElementById("FrontRight_1");
SVGSVGElement svg      = g.getOwnerSVGElement();

SVGPoint pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
pt.setX(190.7826f);
pt.setY(1756.51f);

SVGMatrix groupTransformMatrix = g.getTransform().getBaseVal().consolidate().getMatrix();

pt = pt.matrixTransform(groupTransformMatrix);
```

Comment: Thank for reply ,
Actually there is no getTransform method available for point , but we can get SVGMatrix .
pt = pt.matrixTransform(groupTransformMatrix);
After above method call , I am getting same point value
Any other way?

Comment: Sorry. You'll need to cast `g` to an `SVGGElement` to be able to use `getTransform()`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank a lot , it's working , but for rotation 180, new coordinate point seem quite not accurate,  will check with another couple of use case.

Comment: Above solution is work if there is no rotation, do you have any other solution

Comment: It will work for any transformation, whether it has rotation of not.  If you are having a problem with a particular case, then post a new question with a code example and we can take a look.

Comment: @amoljdv06 Example works for me if I change the order of transformations (make rotate and then translate)